# price comparison website - crawler

Tags: php, javascript, web-crawler

i have got a price comparison website.
You can click on a link of an offer and i'll get $1 from the shop.

The problem is: crawlers crawling the whole website. So they "click on the links".
How can i prevent them from clicking? Javascript is a bad solution.

Thank you!

Comment: how about create some patterns and use regex to check to avoid "click" on them

Comment: theoretically... but not all crawlers know this "rule".

Comment: do you mean your own crawler to craw your target website or search engine robots?

Comment: [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

Comment: @VitoNordloh - how can you identify a crawler as opposed to a genuine user?

Comment: robots.txt is a bad solutions, too. Some crawlers will ignore that file.

Comment: @andrewsi: i would use javascript and a timer. After one second all links were converted to "real links". But that solutions is bad, i think.

Comment: @VitoNordloh - that doesn't answer the question. How can you tell that one user is real, and one user is a bot?

Comment: @andrewsi: that is the problem - there is no way. But the most crawlers won't wait till javascript converted the links after one second.

Comment: You could check the user-agent that the request is coming from and only process the backend if the user agent is a known browser.

Comment: @VitoNordloh if crawlers ignore things, there is nothing you can do. You put up the correct rules, they break them. Only way to get around that is for you to detect them [probably manually] and block them.

Comment: @VitoNordloh - Then what's wrong with your solution about waiting for a second before converting the links?

Comment: @andrewsi: there could be a better solution... maybe...

Comment: @VitoNordloh - I've just added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

1. Use "rel=nofollow" to instruct crawlers not to follow your links.
2. Block certain user-agent strings
3. Use robots.txt to exclude spread of your site.

Unfortunately, none of the above will exclude badly-behaved crawlers. The only solution to actually *prevent* crawlers is some kind of JavaScript link or a CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this the wrong way.

I agree with everything that @yttriuszzerbus says above - add a robots.txt to the file, add "rel=nofollow" to links, and block the user agents that you know about.

So if you've got someone who's now trying to click on a link, it's either a live person, or a badly behaved bot that you don't want clicking.

So how about doing something strange to create the links to the shop sites? Normally, you'd never, ever do this, as it makes your site impossible to index. But that's not an issue - all the well-behaved bots won't be indexing those links because they'll be obeying the robots.txt file.

I'm thinking of something like not having an `<a href=` tag in there - instead, generate the text of the link adding underlining to the font using a stylesheet, so it looks like a link to a normal user, and then having a javascript onClick function that redirects the user when they click on it. Bots won't see it as a link, and users won't notice a thing.

Comment: Some bots may search for non-linked URLs in text to pick up references/mentions

Answer (score 0):

I also have similar project.
My problem was solved only by block certain user-agent strings.

Another problem is that I don't know every "bad" user-agent's, so when a new crawler enters the site, I add it to the blacklist and retroactively remove its visits from statistics.

"rel=nofollow" and robots.txt not work at all for me.